# Play framework 2.0 and JPA : generate ddl script file

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.0

using EBean, play framework 2.0 is able to generate ddl script file. What about JPA/Hibernate ?
I came across documentation and searched around the web and I'm not able to find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate can (since way back); search for the Hibernate "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" setting, or its org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport class.

JPA defines a standardized "schema generation" feature since 2.1.